# Abstract Class confusion

Tags: c#

I have learnt so far that abstract classes can't be instantiated because they are only there for other classes to inherit from. But i cant get my head around this code i came across in the msdn library:

```
WebRequest myRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.contoso.com");
```

in the documentation it says the above code returns a WebRequest instance.

but the WebRequest class is an abstract class, and how comes the above code returns an instance of an abstract class when abstract classes can't be instantiated.

please relieve me from my agony.

Comment: `Create` is a method in the abstract class `WebRequest`. Nothing says that it has to **return** a value of type `WebRequest`. Almost certainly it actually returns an object of a subclass defined within the original class.

Comment: Great Question!

Answer (score 9):

Most likely, the `Create` method in that example will return an instance of a *subclass* of `WebRequest`.

To see *exactly* what you're getting back, you could try something like this:

```
WebRequest myRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.contoso.com");
Type t = myRequest.GetType();
Console.WriteLine(t.Name);
```

Comment: That is probably the greatest tip to descover and debug code. Thnx so much

Answer (score 5):

Abstract classes can't be instantiated immediately. That is, you can't do `new SomeAbstractClass()`. However, you can instantiate subclasses of an abstract class. So abstract classes are similar in function to interfaces, except that they can contain method definitions and member fields.

As such, abstract classes are great for introducing a level of abstraction. The `WebRequest` class is a good example here: It has subclasses for various protocols such as HTTP or HTTPS. When you instantiate a request via `WebRequest.Create("https://example.com/")`, you get a web request instance that can handle the HTTPS protocol, but is also a `WebRequest` instance. The static method `Create(…)` is a *factory method*.

See also the [documentation for `WebRequest.Create(…)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw00b1dc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: “It has subclasses for various protocols such as HTTP or HTTPS.” I think that's a bad example, because HTTP and HTTPS both use the same subclass (`HttpWebRequest`). There are separate classes for the FTP and `file://` protocols though.

Answer (score 3):

`WebRequest` is an abstract class that can't be instantiated. `WebRequest.Create` is a static method that returns a concrete type of `System.Net.HttpWebRequest` that is a derived subclass of `System.Net.WebRequest`. Because it is a derived type, it still identifies itself as a `WebRequest` even though it's fully qualified type name is `System.Net.HttpWebRequest`.

The reason this is useful is that you no longer need to care about the actual implementation. You know that a `WebRequest` will have all of the functionality you need so if the concrete type is a `System.Net.HttpWebRequest` or a `Steves.Awesome.WebRequest` or a `Georges.NotSoAwesome.WebRequest` it doesn't matter because they're all inherited from `WebRequest`.

Your line of code:

```
WebRequest myRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.contoso.com");
```

This isn't saying that it's actually going to create a `WebRequest` and only a `WebRequest`. It's saying that whatever is created will inherit from `WebRequest` and be compatible with anything you need going forward from the standpoint.